# Bitbucket cannot found image from hub.docker.com

Tags: docker, bitbucket

I know this is could be a stupid question, but I'm really get stuck.

I want to use this image in my Bitbucket pipeline: https://hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android .
In `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` I wrote:

```
image:  "hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android"
```

When I run the pipeline, I get the next error:

> rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image
> "hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android:latest": failed to resolve
> reference "hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android:latest":
> hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android:latest: not found

I tried also

```
image:  hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android
```

and

```
image:  hub.docker.com/r/tafilz/xamarin-android:29
```

with the same result.

What I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image name in case if its hosted on Docker hub

```
image: tafilz/xamarin-android
```

Incase if its in private Hub, you should include the URL:

```
image: docker.someprovider.com/account-name/openjdk:8
```

For More infomration:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/